# VBA: Creating a Pivot Table with long caracters

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am trying to create a simple pivot table with the following code:

```
Dim rngA As Range
Dim rngB As Range
Set rngA = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4:G10")
Set rngB = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("Q2")

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rngA, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=rngB, TableName:="My_Pivot_Table", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

My data countains lines of text which are really long (up to 900 caracters), => this is the reason why my VBA Code can not create the table. With shorter text or with the Macro recorder it works.

I am getting 2 different errors:

> 1. If I exchange ".Create" for ".Add" I get: "Compile error : Named argument not found" on the word "Version" in the last line of code.
> 2. with .create I get "type Mismatch",

and it seems different from the other questions I found on Stackoverflow.

Any idea how to fix it?

EDIT: 
The Code works if I exchange

```
SourceData:=rngA
```

with

```
SourceData:="Sheet1!R4C3:R10C7"
```

Comment: `Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)` This bracket seems to be out of place..?

Comment: The bracket was correct with .create. And as Jpad mentionned, .Add doesn t take Version as argument, so you are right, no bracket there

Answer (score 0):

PivotCaches.Add does not take Version as an argument

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pivotcaches.add.aspx

So if you remove that, you are left with: (Which compiles)

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, 
SourceData:=rngA).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=rngB, 
TableName:="My_Pivot_Table", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

However, I think the correct code is more like this:

```
Dim rngA As Range
Dim rngB As Range

Set rngA = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G4:G10")
Set rngB = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("Q2")

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rngA, 
                 Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= rngB, 
                     TableName:="My_Table", DefaultVersion:=6
```

Comment: Thanks for the short explanation. I tried your 2 codes but it didn t solve my issue (the texts were too long to be taken into the pivot table).